# Blazor .NET 8 preview 7 rendering modes

Tags: asp.net-core, server, blazor, render, .net-8.0

In Blazor on .NET 7 in server mode, I could choose between:

- `RenderMode.Server` = which will execute `onInitialize` only once
- `RenderMode.ServerPrerendered` = which will execute `onInitialize` twice

In both these render modes, the page will be interactive for example the counter button will increase the value.

But in .NET 8, I am not able to switch between the two.

If I remove the `@attribute [RenderModeServer]`, the counter button will not increase the value it looks like a static page the equivalent of `RenderMode.Static`.

If I add `@attribute [RenderModeServer]`, then the page will become interactive, but again the component is rendered twice which is not what I want.

How can I choose the `RenderMode.Server` (not `Prerendered`) in Blazor on .NET 8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-5/#enable-interactivity-for-individual-components-with-blazor-server) related

You may try

```
@attribute [RenderModeServer(false)]
```

[image]

Comment: this is the correct answer. it worked straight from the start.

TIP for future readers: make sure u don't cofuse that attribute with this class
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web.serverrendermode?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: In .NET 8 : `@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false))`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#prerendering